# How to validate Filter results using selenium webdriver

Tags: validation, selenium, search, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can you please help how to validate the Filter results. Right now i have a table with columns(Store ID, Manager Name, General manager,Total transactions), here under general manager there are multiple general mangers(abc,pqr,xyz). Here my scenario is i need to filter general manager "pqr". I am able to go to the filter, select the GM "pqr" and click on filter, the result appears on table but how to validate the results using selenium webdriver. There are almost 1000+...

Comment: Do you need to check all 1000+, or do you need to check that a new transaction appears in there, and maybe a select 1 or 2 old ones appear?

Answer (score 0):

### Using Excel sheets , Apache POI and Map data structure.

1. Store your expected test data in excel sheet.
2. Pass each row data using map object to your test method.
3. Iterate over each cell data using loops and extract cell value.
4. Compare cell value with map keys 1:1.

That's how you can validate tables with large entries using selenium-webdriver.

Comment: But here expected records are dynamic it will increase continuously. For example if i filter GM "pqr" at this time assume i got 100 records later if do same i might get 150.

Comment: For dynamic data , you cannot apply exact assertions via test-automation. Either refine your filter to a targeted set of records OR do continuous update of test data sheets. If the table is increasing in size, then go Adhoc. Assert sample row data.